# Nginx http_referrer hostname regex?

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to redirect other websites that contain a specific word in the hostname. I use the following code in my vhost file:

```
if ($http_referer ~* "hostname1|hostname2" ) {
    rewrite ^ http://www.example.com;
}
```

Only problem is, its matching even pages on my site that contain the text. What do i use so it only matches hostnames (the text before the TLD) ?

Comment: $http_referer isn't what you think it is.  Why not simply make a virtual server for those names that redirects everything?

Comment: They aren't domains i own though.  For instance, lets say example.com links to my website, i want all traffic from example.com to redirect to other.com

Comment: @Ruok2bu What do you mean by *"links to my website"* ? How is it bad to get links pointing to your website ? I don't get it.

Comment: It's a website for a video game, i dont want cheating/hacking sites linking to it that are promoting game cheats for the game.